# MO's Algorithm to find number of elements present in both array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sub-array

I have *2* arrays, `before[N+1]`(*1* indexed) and `after[]` (subarray of `before[]`). Now for *M* Queries, I need to find how many elements of `after[]` are present in `before[]` for the given range `l,r`.

For example:
N = 5
Before: (2, 1, 3, 4, 5)
After: (1, 3, 4, 5)
M = 2
L = 1, R = 5 → 4 elements (1, 3, 4, 5) of after[] are present in between before[1] and before[5]
L = 2, R = 4 → 3 elements (1, 3, 4) of after[] are present in between before[2] and before[4]

I am trying to use MO's algorithm to find this.Following is my code :

```
using namespace std;

int N, Q;

// Variables, that hold current "state" of computation
long long current_answer;
long long cnt[100500];

// Array to store answers (because the order we achieve them is messed up)
long long answers[100500];
int BLOCK_SIZE;


// We will represent each query as three numbers: L, R, idx. Idx is 
// the position (in original order) of this query.
pair< pair<int, int>, int> queries[100500];


// Essential part of Mo's algorithm: comparator, which we will
// use with std::sort. It is a function, which must return True
// if query x must come earlier than query y, and False otherwise.
inline bool mo_cmp(const pair< pair<int, int>, int> &x,
        const pair< pair<int, int>, int> &y)
{
    int block_x = x.first.first / BLOCK_SIZE;
    int block_y = y.first.first / BLOCK_SIZE;
    if(block_x != block_y)
        return block_x < block_y;
    return x.first.second < y.first.second;
}

// When adding a number, we first nullify it's effect on current
// answer, then update cnt array, then account for it's effect again.
inline void add(int x)
{
    current_answer -= cnt[x] * cnt[x] * x;
    cnt[x]++;
    current_answer += cnt[x] * cnt[x] * x;
}

// Removing is much like adding.
inline void remove(int x)
{
    current_answer -= cnt[x] * cnt[x] * x;
    cnt[x]--;
    current_answer += cnt[x] * cnt[x] * x;
}

int main()
{
    cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin >> N >> Q;    // Q- number of queries
    BLOCK_SIZE = static_cast<int>(sqrt(N));


   long long int before[N+1];   // 1 indexed
   long long int after[]        // subarray

    // Read input queries, which are 0-indexed. Store each query's 
    // original position. We will use it when printing answer.
    for(long long int i = 0; i < Q; i++) {
        cin >> queries[i].first.first >> queries[i].first.second;
        queries[i].second = i;
    }

    // Sort queries using Mo's special comparator we defined.
    sort(queries, queries + Q, mo_cmp);

    // Set up current segment [mo_left, mo_right].
    int mo_left = 0, mo_right = -1;

    for(long long int i = 0; i < Q; i++) {
        // [left, right] is what query we must answer now.
        int left = queries[i].first.first;
        int right = queries[i].first.second;

        // Usual part of applying Mo's algorithm: moving mo_left
        // and mo_right.
        while(mo_right < right) {
            mo_right++;
            add(after[mo_right]);
        }
        while(mo_right > right) {
            remove(after[mo_right]);
            mo_right--;
        }

        while(mo_left < left) {
            remove(after[mo_left]);
            mo_left++;
        }
        while(mo_left > left) {
            mo_left--;
            add(after[mo_left]);
        }

        // Store the answer into required position.
        answers[queries[i].second] = current_answer;
    }

    // We output answers *after* we process all queries.
    for(long long int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
        cout << answers[i] << "\n";
```

Now the problem is I can't figure out how to define `add function` and `remove function`.

Can someone help me out with these functions ?

Comment: Are the elements in before[] unique? If so, why not make an boolean array mark[], in which mark[i] represents whether before[i] appears in after[]? Then the query (l, r) becomes counting number of true between mark[l] and mark[r].

Comment: If `after[]` is ***subarray*** of `before[]` then `NumberOfOccurrence(NOC)` can never be more than `NumberOfElements(An)` in `after[]`. `NOC=max(r-l+1, An)`

Comment: @MoTao No, the elements in `before[]` aren't unique.

Comment: @sameerkn I don't think this formula will hold for every case.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'll denote the given arrays as `a` and `b`.

1. Let's learn how to add a new position (move right by one). If `a[r]` is already there, you can just ignore it. Otherwise, we need to add `a[r]` and add the number of occurrences of `b[r]` in `a` so far to the answer. Finally, if `b[r]` is already in `a`, we need to add one to the answer. Note that we need two count to arrays to do that: one for the first array and one for the second.
2. We know how to add one position in `O(1)`, so we're almost there. How do we handle deletions?
3. Let's assume that we want to remove a subsegment. We can easily modify the count arrays. But how do we restore the answer? Well, we don't. Your solution goes like this:

   - save the current answer
   - add a subsegment
   - answer the query
   - remove it (we take care about the count arrays and ignore the answer)
   - restore the saved answer

That's it. It would require rebuilding the structure when we move the left pointer to the next block, but it still requires `O(N sqrt(N))` time in the worst case.

Note: it might be possible to recompute the answer directly using count arrays when we remove one position, but the way I showed above looks easier too me.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How do I implement this with the code ? Can you help me with the code ? I can't figure out the code for add and remove.